# How to loop date range for loan amortization based on monthly or weekly

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Am developing loan amortization schedule and will need a help of date looping. I have been able to get the schedule for the payment but will need help with the date inclusive. Please help me with the date looping.
Thanks

```
echo '<table border="1">';
echo '<tr><th>#</th><th>PAYMENT</th><th>INTEREST</th><th>PRINCIPAL</th><th>BALANCE</th></tr>';
$start_date = '2014-12-14';
$end_date = '2015-03-12';
$count = 0;
do {
   $count++;

   // calculate interest on outstanding balance
   $interest = $balance * $rate/100;

   // what portion of payment applies to principal?
   $principal = $payment - $interest;

   // watch out for balance < payment
   if ($balance < $payment) {
      $principal = $balance;
      $payment   = $interest + $principal;
   } // if

   // reduce balance by principal paid
   $balance = $balance - $principal;

   // watch for rounding error that leaves a tiny balance
   if ($balance < 0) {
      $principal = $principal + $balance;
      $interest  = $interest - $balance;
      $balance   = 0;
   } // if

   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>$count</td>";
   echo "<td>" .number_format($payment,   2, ".", ",") ."</td>";
   echo "<td>" .number_format($interest,  2, ".", ",") ."</td>";
   echo "<td>" .number_format($principal, 2, ".", ",") ."</td>";
   echo "<td>" .number_format($balance,   2, ".", ",") ."</td>";
   echo "</tr>";

   @$totPayment   = $totPayment + $payment;
   @$totInterest  = $totInterest + $interest;
   @$totPrincipal = $totPrincipal + $principal;

   if ($payment < $interest) {
      echo "</table>";
      echo "<p>Payment < Interest amount - rate is too high, or payment is too low</p>";
      exit;
   } // if

} while ($balance > 0);

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
echo "<td><b>" .number_format($totPayment,   2, ".", ",") ."</b></td>";
echo "<td><b>" .number_format($totInterest,  2, ".", ",") ."</b></td>";
echo "<td><b>" .number_format($totPrincipal, 2, ".", ",") ."</b></td>";
echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify on how you want the dates looped. I do not see date variables used only declared. Also, you tag MySQL but I am not seeing a query in your code. Do values for `$interest`, `$payment`, `$balance` derive from your database? Each by specific dates? Then all your calculated fields and if/then logic can be written in a SQL query and iterated out into a PHP array that outputs to table rows and cells.

Comment: The $interest, $payment are required by users to input from a form. Do not loop with MySQL, may be if you can help me out with the mysql looping. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$timestampInOneWeek = strtotime('+1 week');
$timestampOneMonthAfter01january = strtotime('+1 month', 1419984000);
```

You can also use [DateTime::add](http://php.net/manual/datetime.add.php)

```
$month_later = new DateTime('2000-01-01');
$month_later->add(new DateInterval('P1M'));
```

Comment: Please what about the looping?

Comment: With this you can loop through weeks and months. Adding a `for/while` is your job.